# Plotting separate Pandas dataframe as barcharts with share x axis

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have fallen headlong into this Pandas trap several times in different guises. On this occasion, I want to plot two barcharts, one above the other, using data from two separate dataframes but each plot having a common x axis.

I have two dataframes as follows:

```
dfA = pd.DataFrame({'year':[2003,2004,2005,2006,2007],
                    'value':[75,84,95,101,119]})

dfA = dfA.set_index('year')

dfB = pd.DataFrame({'year':[2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005],
                    'value':[34,46,64,71,88,93]})

dfB = dfB.set_index('year')
```

The dataframes appear as:

```
      value
year       
2003     75
2004     84
2005     95
2006    101
2007    119

      value
year       
2000     34
2001     46
2002     64
2003     71
2004     88
2005     93
```

I then try to plot the graphs as follows:

```
fig, axarr = plt.subplots(2,
                          figsize = (4,6),
                          sharex = True)

dfA['value'].plot(kind = 'bar',
                  ax = axarr[0],
                  sharex = True,
                  title = 'DF A')

dfB['value'].plot(kind = 'bar',
                  ax = axarr[1],
                  sharex = True,
                  title = 'DF B')

plt.show()
```

The graphs that are produced show the correct bar heights but the x axes are clearly not shared but instead the bars seem to be plotted one after the other and aligned to the left hand column; the labels used for the x axis are simply the labels from the bottom plot.
[image: Bar-plots from different dataframes]

One work around it is to outer join both dataframes and then plot each column. (On reflection, this solution is similar to the answer given by #gyx-hh at [Plotting Pandas data as an array of bar chart does not honour sharex = True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54327324/plotting-pandas-data-as-an-array-of-bar-chart-does-not-honour-sharex-true).) Outer joining the dataframes works but it works regardless of whether `sharex = True` is set because the full set of values is present for each dataset even though some cells may contain NaN.

```
dfC = dfA.join(dfB,
               how = 'outer',
               lsuffix = '_A',
               rsuffix = '_B')

      value_A  value_B
year                  
2000      NaN     34.0
2001      NaN     46.0
2002      NaN     64.0
2003     75.0     71.0
2004     84.0     88.0
2005     95.0     93.0
2006    101.0      NaN
2007    119.0      NaN
```

[image: Bar-plot with correct x axis]

I really like the `pandas.plot()` method but, for me, this is a very serious glitch that could lead to data being misinterpreted. Should this be raised as a bug with the pandas team or is there a reason why this behaviour is preferable?

Answer (score 1):

To validate your observation, I think that's messed up.

#### `align`

This is essentially doing the same thing as your `join`.

```
fig, axarr = plt.subplots(2, figsize=(4,6), sharex=True)

# vvv Thing I Added vvv
dfA, dfB = dfA.align(dfB, axis=0)

dfA['value'].plot.bar(ax=axarr[0], title='DF A')
dfB['value'].plot.bar(ax=axarr[1], title='DF A')
```

[image]

Comment: It may be doing the same thing but I hadn't come across align before so a very useful answer. Thanks.